# AWS iOS cloudwatch describeLogStreams uploadsequencetoken empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-sdk-ios, amplify-ios

Earlier was getting access denied for describeLogStreams and after adding the necessary policy got that fixed but now there is response but uploadSequenceToken (and nextToken) are empty.

```
    AWSLogs.default().describeLogStreams(req!) { (response, error) in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            Logging.logError("ERROR: AWS CW describe Log Stream error: \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            self.nextSequenceToken = response?.logStreams?.first?.uploadSequenceToken
// ^^^^^ above value is nil
        }
```

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log stream looks empty. Maybe there is none for now.

Comment: This helped. Looks like first time around, need to send some logs even with upload token is empty.